# Registering a ConstraintValidator implementation to Constraint

Tags: java, spring, validation, constraints

Due t app's architecture I need to decouple constraint annotation from its implementation. I was thinking about using approach used in `@Size` annotation, when `validatedBy` property isn't set explicitly:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
public @interface Size { .. }
```

But I can't find any information of how to register implementation to this constraint, registering the component via spring's `@Component` doesn't help and code fails with: `No validator could be found for constraint`

Answer (score 1):

JSR-303 let you declare constraints in a [constraint-mappings](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#d0e5931) file.

You can then either

- reference the constraint-mapping file in your [validation.xml](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#xml-config).

  ```
  <constraint-mapping>META-INF/validation/order-constraints.xml</constraint-mapping>
  ```

or

- add the constraint-mappings file using the java api [Configuration.addMapping(InputString)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/1.0/api/javax/validation/Configuration.html#addMapping(java.io.InputStream))

  > Add a stream describing constraint mapping in the Bean Validation XML format.